# C# Webbrowser will not fully load webpage

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Was creating a browser and was testing how different websites load and noticed on some website the C# web browser will not fully load specific websites. Seems to default to mobile maybe?

[For example, Apartmentbutler.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfn5M.png)

[Compared to full browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkok7.jpg)

[Another example, cleancloudapp, gets stuck here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6fXg.png)

For sake of details - very basic.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string webPage = textBox1.Text.Trim();
            webBrowser1.Navigate(webPage);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this something because of the webdeveloper? If it's because mobile, why not loading properly? Can I use useragent to force to desktop?

Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkok7.jpg - Desktop Version

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6fXg.png - Another website, cleancloud, loading issue example

Answer (score 0):

By default, the WebBrowser control runs in compatibility view mode. Compatibility view mode is basically document mode 7. That most likely caused the rendering issue.

You can change the IE version for webbrowser control by adding HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\yourapp.exe and set its DWord value to e.g. 11001 (IE 11)

For 32 bits machine add under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\

Details at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation